# How to make globally accessible info through Context API to be saved locally to persist across a refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to manage user login with context API and here's my auth.js:

```
 const AuthContext = createContext({
    isAuthenticated: false
});

class AuthProvider extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: false
        };
        this.signIn = this.signIn.bind(this);
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    }


    /**
     * signIn function
     */
    signIn() {
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true }), 1000);
    }

    /**
     * logOut function
     */
    logout(){
        setTimeout(()=>this.setState({isAuthenticated:false}),1000);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{
                isAuthenticated: this.state.isAuthenticated,
                signIn: this.signIn,
                logout:this.logout,
                getStatus:this.getStatus
            }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

const AuthConsumer = AuthContext.Consumer;

export {AuthProvider,AuthConsumer};
```

And I have some protected routes, here's my ProtectedRoute component:

```
    export default function ProtectedRoute({...props }) {

  return (
        <AuthConsumer>
          {({ isAuthenticated }) => (
            <Route
              render={() =>
                isAuthenticated ?
                <Redirect to="/" />  :
                (
                  <Route {...props} />
              )}
            />
          )}
        </AuthConsumer>
      );
}
```

And a Protected Route like login, Registration component and ... would be sth like this:

```
 <ProtectedRoute exact path="/profile" component={UserProfile}/>
```

Now if you login from login page and use the signIn function the, the **isAuthenticated** flag from AuthProvider would be set to ***true*** ergo you wouldn't be able to go to login or registration page after login(they R protected and trying to access them would redirect you to homePage ), everything works fine as long as you try to manually change the addressbar to the desired path(say "/login") from the address bar and that is when **isAuthenticated** flag gets set to ***false*** like no login has happened before, **so my question is why is it not working like promised in this case and what I should do to protect the routes completely ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Umair Farooq "The state of the application is re-initialized to default when it is reloaded", so how to make the shared global state to persist across a refresh? We use localStorage from `window`object so the code in auth.js will change into this:

```
//auth.js
......
let localState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hasLoggedIn"));
```

Here, we’re going to pull in whatever value might be stored locally as "hasLoggedIn" and parse it into a JSON object (local storage can only store strings, so we have to parse it back and forth).
Next we are going to change initial state in the constructor as such(we’re going to set the initial state of to the localState if it exists, and, otherwise, the initialState that we defined earlier):

```
//auth.js
....
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: null,
            isAuthenticated: false || localState
        };
        this.signIn = this.signIn.bind(this);
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    }
```

Next, we are going to modify the "signIn" & "logout" functions as such:

```
//auth.js
....
 signIn() {
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true },()=>{
            localStorage.setItem("hasLoggedIn",true);
        }), 1000);
    }

    /**
     * logOut function
     */
    logout(){
        setTimeout(()=>this.setState({isAuthenticated:false},()=>{
            localStorage.removeItem("hasLoggedIn");
        }),1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because on changing the url it reloads the page which re-initialize the state the its default state. In single page applications(React, vue) the state of applications is re-initialize to default when reloaded.

The solution for this is the save token(or authentication identifier used) in local storage and and initialize the state of app from the local storage

Comment: Can you provide me with an example on how to update and change the "isAuthenticated"  flag based on a value stored in localStorage on page reload/refreshing?